# Google Place Picker will be removed?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps-api-3, maps, gmsplacepicker

Hi today google send me this email about all my application that use Google Place picker in ios and android.

*Today we're launching upgraded Places SDKs for Android and iOS. They are pay-as-you-go and billed at the same rate as our Places API and Places Library in the Maps JavaScript API. You can visit the Android and iOS migration guides to install the new SDKs.
Effective January 29, 2019, the upgraded Places SDKs for Android and iOS will replace the existing versions of the Places SDKs - please read our documentation for more information. The existing Places SDKs (including the Place Picker feature) can continue being used by current customers of these SDKs until July 29, 2019. In order to avoid service disruption, please start using the upgraded SDK versions before July 29, 2019.
We have identified that your projects listed below are using Places API and will be impacted by this change:

#

We have noticed that you do not have a billing account with a valid form of payment. Please update your billing account and associate it to your project(s) by July 29, 2019 to avoid service interruption.
We understand this announcement may have an impact on your implementations. If you have any questions, or require further assistance, please contact Google Maps Platform Support.*

Does this means that by by July 29, 2019 all my apps that use Place Picker will not function correctly because Google decided to remove it? 
What am i suppose to do? Really confused again. Thanks Google!

Comment: Google is tracking the interest in having a Place Picker widget here: (Android) https://issuetracker.google.com/128304810, (iOS) https://issuetracker.google.com/128304760. Please fill the linked form with your use case and needs if you are interested.

Answer (score 3):

My app heavily depended on the PlacePicker and It was free. Though there is a migration guide, but the new APIs are not free and have an upper cap on free usage. SO I built a Place picker that lets you pick places from a map using Geocoder and its free Check it out: https://github.com/suchoX/PlacePicker

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the placepicker UI that they provided will no longer be available. You will have to find a replacement for the UI or come up with something on your own. You can still use the SDK to get autocompletion in order to simulate what the placepicker was doing. Everything that made the placepicker UI work is still there, they are just deprecating and no longer supporting the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It says what you are supposed to do in the email google sent you. From yesterday, you have up to July 29, 2019 to implement and start using the updated SDK versions just for the  Places API in place of the old. Once you have done this release it. Make sure you do this for all your apps that are effected by this update. If you don't do this, your apps can possibly still function but that feature will not.

EDIT:

[On this page](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker) you can see the Deprecation notice

[image]
When you click the Android Migration we can see that you can install the compatibility library to continue using the Place Picker during the deprecation period. After this the place picker will no longer work. 
[image]

Looks like you have to find another way to do what the place picker is currently doing for you.

Comment: Yes but they say PlacePicker will be removed so there is nothing ready to use. I am going to have to create a place-picker myself?

Comment: See edit. You could but they must be replacing it with something surely, I just cant find it.

Comment: The part that is not so clear is if the applications that already has it will still function

Answer (score -1):

Place Picker old version will be turned off from jul 29 2019 but migration option available

[Migration Guide here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration)

Comment: It's for using the Place Picker through the deprecation period only.

Comment: after deprecation period what will happen

Comment: comments please

Comment: yes, deprecation is a notice period to find an alternative. after the period it will be removed.

Comment: is any alternate place picker after it removed

Comment: one 3rd party is here: https://github.com/rtchagas/pingplacepicker, also please check key difference here: https://github.com/rtchagas/pingplacepicker#a-key-difference